# Callback to C++ code if user try to call undefined function of C++ object from JS

Tags: c++, v8

I am creating a V8 wrapper to my C++ object by using `v8::ObjectTemplate`. But on the step of generation this template I don't have full type info about C++ object and as result on JS runtime I have JS object with incomplete list of functions and properties.

And now if user try call a function that I not describe in `ObjectTemplate`, V8 just throw an exception in script.

Is there way to set callback which will invoke before an exception will throw?

This callback should make a deep search of user called function and return execution result it successful found.

```cpp
//c++
class A{
public:
 static int f1(){return 1;}
 static int f2(){return 2;}
};

void create_v8_template(){
 v8::Local<v8::ObjectTemplate> template_base = v8::ObjectTemplate::New(isolate);
 obj_template->Set(v8pp::to_v8(isolate, "f1"), v8::FunctionTemplate::New(isolate, A::f1));
}
```

```js
//js
a.f1(); //success
a.f2();// throw exception: "a.f2 is not a function". I need that V8 will invoke my callback there instead the exception
```

Comment: Consider providing a [mcve].

Comment: Does not answer your question, but might help you with your further research: It might be possible because you can do something like that using [Proxy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy) objects using [handler.get()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy/handler/get), so it is likely that you can hook into the `get` process on the c++ side aswell.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to automatically map JavaScript method/property lookups to C++ method/property names. One reason for this is that regular Release-mode C++ binaries don't even contain those names any more. This is *usually* not a problem/limitation because C++ classes are statically  known at compile time, they can't be extended dynamically later.

I can think of two cases where you don't have statically known classes, and corresponding approaches to solve them:

If you know the superset of possibly existing functions, you can register them all on the `ObjectTemplate`, and then when a method is called, check whether it actually exists, and otherwise return `undefined` (or whatever) from your C++ callback. This might work well e.g. if you have a set of subclasses, where any one of them can get instantiated to fill the role of the C++ object.

If you want to expose an arbitrary key/value structure (e.g. a database, or something that was parsed from JSON, etc) as an object to JavaScript, where you truly have no idea at compile time what might be valid keys, then you can use V8's [interceptors](https://v8.dev/docs/embed#interceptors) API. That essentially boils down to telling V8 "whenever any property is requested from this object, first ask this callback whether that property exists". Of course in the interceptor callback, you then need a way to find out whether the property (`f2` in your example) exists.